# grunt cssmin - "#<Object> has no method 'options'"

Tags: gruntjs

I'm setting up a Wordpress development environment on Windows 8 based on the suggestions in [this article](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/how-to-optimize-your-wordpress-development-workflow/). I'm almost done, but when I  try to run grunt.cmd from the command line, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'options' at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Petter\PhpstormProjects\NHFL\src\node_modules\grunt-css\tasks\grunt-css.js:74:24)
at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Petter\PhpstormProjects\NHFL\src\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\task.js:109:15)
at Object.thisTask.fn (c:\Users\Petter\PhpstormProjects\NHFL\src\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\task.js:58:16)
at Task.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Petter\PhpstormProjects\NHFL\src\node_modules\grunt\lib\util\task.js:343:36)
at Task.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Petter\PhpstormProjects\NHFL\src\node_modules\grunt\lib\util\task.js:319:9)
at Task.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Petter\PhpstormProjects\NHFL\src\node_modules\grunt\lib\util\task.js:346:11)
at Task.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Petter\PhpstormProjects\NHFL\src\node_modules\grunt\lib\util\task.js:319:9)
at Object.exports.consoleOutput (c:\Users\Petter\PhpstormProjects\NHFL\src\node_modules\grunt-compass\tasks\lib\compass.js:138:13)
at puts (c:\Users\Petter\PhpstormProjects\NHFL\src\node_modules\grunt-compass\tasks\compass.js:16:21)
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:635:7)
```

My default task looks like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', 'lint concat min compass cssmin');
```

The cssmin config section looks like this:

```
    cssmin: {
        my_target: {
            options: {
                keepSpecialComments: 1
            },
            src: ['<banner:meta.wpblock>', '../sass/style.css'],
            dest: '../build/style.css'
        }
    }
```

When I remove cssmin from the default task, it runs without error, so I guess that's where the error is, but I can't figure out what it is. I've played with various config options to see if I can get it to work, but so far no luck.

Answer (score 0):

That article is very out of date and geared towards Grunt v0.3 (v0.4 was released about a year ago).

Please refer to this getting started guide on the official docs: http://gruntjs.com/getting-started

and review the migration guide from v0.3 to v0.4: http://gruntjs.com/upgrading-from-0.3-to-0.4

Lastly, take a look at the examples for the specific task you're using, cssmin: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin#usage-examples